# Check Index Fragementation Query

Tags: sql-server-2005, index

I'm completely stumped.  I'm a relatively new SQL Server DBA so I'm at a loss with the following situation; hoping maybe someone had an idea.

I have a new production SQL Server (Windows Server 2003/SQL Server 2005 SP3)  that I am going to be responsible for.  Wanted to get some basic stats so I got some scripts off of SQLServerPedia to help with that. (Great stuff btw).

Did a check on index fragmentation and ran the following query (took it about 30 min to run)...

```
SELECT
      db.name AS databaseName
    , SCHEMA_NAME(obj.schema_id) AS schemaName
    , OBJECT_NAME(ps.OBJECT_ID) AS tableName
    , ps.OBJECT_ID AS objectID
    , ps.index_id AS indexID
    , ps.partition_number AS partitionNumber
    , ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS fragmentation
    , ps.page_count
FROM sys.databases db
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL, N'Limited') ps
      ON db.database_id = ps.database_id
  INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON ps.object_id = obj.object_id
WHERE ps.index_id > 0 
   AND ps.page_count > 100 
   AND ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30
ORDER BY databaseName, schemaName, tableName
OPTION (MaxDop 1);
```

This came back with several rows of data with several indexes for several databases.  (I didn't save the result set of the query -- wish I had now).  Long story short I re-ran the query about ten minutes later and it ran in 2 seconds and returned no rows.  Nothing.  I have run 0 queries to manipulate indexes in that timeframe.  No jobs had run.  There is nothing in the SQL Server Log for that time period to indicate anything fishy.  And I double checked and confirmed the query was run both times on the same server.  How could this be?  How could approx. 20 indexes that were over 30% fragmentation with more than 100 page count suddenly be taken care of (or disappear from this result set) without me doing anything (or from what I can tell -- no one else or no other application) doing anything either?

Answer (score 4):

I think you ran the query from 2 different databases (same server, but different databases) and are getting unexpected results due to the INNER JOIN condition.

My suggestion would be to just focus on one database at a time when analyzing indexes.

Comment: Add USE [DB Name] so you know it focuses on one DB each time you run it.

Comment: FYI, if you haven't looked at it yet, I'd recommend the Index Defrag tool from SQL Fool, current version 4.1 at http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Pinal Dave's](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/27/sql-server-2005-find-index-fragmentation-details-slow-index-performance/) script to find bloated indexes. Most of the time it runs in under 13 seconds.

Comment: Another good one is Ola Hallengren's DB maintenance script. It includes a snippet on managing index frag: http://ola.hallengren.com/Versions.html

Comment: Yeah this worked ok.  At least I get a result set now, just not what I had before.  I still don't know what happened, but I guess I just need to move on.

Comment: Totally, that script was a good start, I have since added more columns so I don't have to work too hard to understand the context of the results.